# how to update iptables in docker?

Tags: docker, iptables

I have got below rules present on one server. There is a separate chain called DOCKER

```
iptables -L
Chain DOCKER (2 references)
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             112.13.0.4           tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             112.13.0.4           tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             112.13.0.4           tcp dpt:ssh
```

I need to add exact same rules one another server. Basically i am trying to expose ports 80, 443 and 22 to the intranet and I have no idea how to do so. I tried looking into iptables documentation but nothing seems straightforward. My question is how do I add above rules to iptables without disturbing existing rules?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to expose ports, all you need to do is give a -p directive on docker run or docker service create. Docker will manage port mappings to the host and the userland proxy will filter traffic accordingly. Firewall rules don't do anything if there's nothing listening on the other side.

`docker run d --name tutum -p 80:80 tutum/hello-world`

```
$:~ user$ docker run -d -p 80:80 --name tutum tutum/hello-world
Unable to find image 'tutum/hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from tutum/hello-world
658bc4dc7069: Pull complete
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete
af3cc4b92fa1: Pull complete
d0034177ece9: Pull complete
983d35417974: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:0d57def8055178aafb4c7669cbc25ec17f0acdab97cc587f30150802da8f8d85
Status: Downloaded newer image for tutum/hello-world:latest
2673c45c70f9ac153236ddb4fbeb4d54e7953742dea60c3f8e3c1e7d718d68e0
$:~ user$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
2673c45c70f9        tutum/hello-world   "/bin/sh -c 'php-fpm…"   4 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp       tutum
```

At this point, the host will be listening on port 80. All you have to do is manage how the traffic gets to the host.